# Booting microzed 7010 board with NFS when initramfs is enabled in kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, xilinx, petalinux

I am using petalinux and vivado 2016.04 and microzed 7010 board for my project.

I have followed the steps =>I have set board in QSPI mode by jumpers. I have TFTPed the imaged.ub on board (run netboot)and mounted the roofs from my PC by NFS.

For this, when NFS is configed in petalinux-config, I had to disable initramfs in kernel config manually.

If I don't disable initramfs in kernel(petalinux-config -c kernel ) but NFS is configured (petalinux-config), rootfs is being mounted from QSPI.

I am beginer to petalinux sdk and microzed board. What is the reson makes it mount rootfs from QSPI even if I configured nfs but did not disable initramfs in kernel and my bootargs is

INPUTS :
1 . "bootargs=console=ttyPS0,115200 earlyprintk root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=172.16.9.187:/tftpboot/nfsroot,tcp,v4 ip=172.16.9.25 rw"

manualy i cross-verified the mounting of rootfs by NFS from PC to board.

2 . "mount -o nolock -t nfs ip_addr:/tftpboot/nfsroot /home/root/"

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Pritam

Comment: The initramfs has precedence over any rootfs specified by the kernel command line.  Presumably there is something in that initramfs that is mounting the fs in the QSPI, and then doing a `chroot` or `pivot_root`.  The boot log might have salient details.

Comment: thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

I have got an useful links for this.

https://landley.net/writing/rootfs-intro.html

https://landley.net/writing/rootfs-howto.html

Answer (score 0):

As @sawdust wrote, any initrd/initramfs takes precedence. Check your `/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/default` for an `INITRD`-line. Even Petalinux 2023.1 will happily bring this line back on every built and make your machine prefer initrd over NFS as long this option is active in the kernel.

Without the kernel support, you still lose some time while PXE transfer the rootfs-file due to the config, although it won't be used.